# Sending SMS in Background

Tags: android, android-service, background-service

Help to solve this issue : When I send a large number of text messages and manage log in text file in Background using My Application, I get this pop up Message after send a message: "messaging is sending a large number of sms messages android application"

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/38461

This must be a system broadcast that you can't avoid as the sending of messages may incur cost to the app user and the android system will notify user about your app.

Answer (score 1):

Android imposes a SMS message per amount of time limit. The default limits for Android 4.0 were 100 messages per hour. However, with Android 4.1 it was decreased to 30 messages in 30 minutes.

During development and debugging work that you are doing, you can install **SMS Limit Tool** and adjust/configure the amount of messages allowed per amount of time.

Google Play Link for SMS Limit Tool:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bamf.smslimittool.donate

That way, you can avoid those Android System warnings for the time being, specially during development/debugging.

Comment: Actually I want to do same from my application with out user interface.

Comment: @JanakPatel:There is SMSDispatcher.java file in Android source code (AOSP),It could be out of date, I can't tell. There you will find below 2 parameters,/** Default checking period for SMS sent without uesr permit */
private static final int DEFAULT_SMS_CHECK_PERIOD = 3600000;

/** Default number of SMS sent in checking period without uesr permit */
private static final int DEFAULT_SMS_MAX_ALLOWED = 100; And as you can see, they are declared as "private". Hence, you need to write nasty code based on "Reflection" to get access to these, as there is no public API exported by Android.

Answer (score 0):

OS will stop you from this, as you'll send a large number of SMS and it is suspicious so the OS will notify the user about this.

Every app declares its permissions when you install it. It doesn’t request permissions — you can’t actually control these permissions. The app tells you what it requires, and you can take it or leave it. Android apps must declare permissions for nearly everything, from Internet access and writing to the SD card to monitoring your location and sending SMS messages.